# How to add YouTube cards to all videos in a playlist?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to add a card to all videos in a playlist? I know of tubebuddy but looking to see if this can be done through the api.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share an example about cars in videos? - I'm not familiar with that feature and I doubt YouTube has this feature on any of its APIs.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! Here is an example of a card. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ff8G1tYHRIg?=t22)

Comment: Sorry, this will take you to the first card in the video.[link]https://youtu.be/ff8G1tYHRIg?t=22